# how to show a response in Razor view

Tags: model-view-controller, razorengine

my index view displays the IEnumberable inside an html table. with the links like edit and delete. delete links is create like below.

```
   @* @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id= SomeId })*@
```

Inside the controlelr action methods i am calling a service that gives me delete functionality.

```
 CustomResponseObject resp = someService.DeleteSomething(id);
```

Now this CustomResponseObject has a bool indicating success or failure. and a string mentioned which business rule was negated if any. I want to propagate this message to the Razor in order to show an alert box.

what will be an ideal solution in this case. ?

Answer (score 0):

I would make an ajax call and than display the message depending on the result as you indicated you wanted display the message in an alert box.

```
$.get("~/Delete", { id: someId }).done(function(data) {
            var result = data.IsSuccess ? "success" : "failure";
            alert("Your operation was a " + result);
        });
```

Sorry I just noticed you wanted to have it available in Razor. In this case I would add a field to your Model. Than in the Razor view you can access it.
As for displaying it maybe have your JS pick up on the hidden field created using

```
Html.HiddenFor(m => m.IsSuccess)
```